# Locater strategy give two results in selenium ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

For all the checkboxes and radio buttons i create a locater builder:

```
LocatorBuilders.add('radio', function(e) {

      var name = e.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('name');
      var value = name + '_' + e.parentElement.getAttribute('value');
      var result = 'radio=' + value;
      return result;

});
```

And a locater strategy:

```
PageBot.prototype.locateElementByRadio = function(locatorString, inDocument, inWindow) {

    var name = locatorString.split('_')[0];
    var value = locatorString.split('_')[1];

    var result = inDocument.querySelector('div[field=' + name +'] label[value=' + value +'] input');

    return result;

}
```

HTML element:

```
<div class="radio" name="radio-example" style="">
    <label class="radio-label" value="male" style="">
         <input class="radio-input" style="" tabindex="1" type="radio">
         <span class="option">Man</span>
     </label>
</div>
```

This works perfect and in my selenium IDE is ee something like radio=new_yes
But when i record a click on a radio i see two commands in selenium ide. One command with the locater builder and one command with a verry long xpath that belong to the label from the checkbox. How can i record only the input field from the checkbox? and not the label ?

[image: Selenium IDE]

Comment: could you share the html for the element in the question as well please.

Comment: Add the html element in the question.

Comment: Are you trying to get the value of the checkbox whether it is checked or not?

Comment: No only select the radiobutton.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to get the locator for the radiobutton, you can use this locator

`css=input.radio-input`

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I would locate elements with the selenium IDE. As you can see it works good with above function. The only thing is that the IDE record two locaters. I would that selenium IDE record only the one with re radio= prefix.